# Android Studio - increase the amount of undos

Tags: android-studio

I am wondering whether there is a way to increase the amount of times one can use the undo button in Android Studio. I couldn't find it in settings. 
At the moment after a few undos, it stops allowing further ones.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since Android Studio is a fork of JetBrains IntelliJ, [this](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/increase-undo-jetbrains-webstorm-intellij/) should work.

Alternative Link: [How to increase undo and redo steps in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967478/how-to-increase-undo-and-redo-steps-in-android-studio/39970026#39970026)

Comment: page is blocked bro

Comment: Your link is dead. Would you mind posting the actual fix?

Comment: The link may be to this stackoverflow titled "[How to increase undo and redo steps in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967478/how-to-increase-undo-and-redo-steps-in-android-studio/39970026#39970026)"

Answer (score 34):

Follow this:

From menu on the top Go to Help > Find Action > Type Registry > It will open Registry Dialog > start typing undo > you will find "undo:globalUndoLimit" > change it from 100 to 1000 or any higher.

Comment: also increase, undo.globalDocumentLimit