# How to increase undo and redo steps in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, undo-redo

How to increase `undo` and `redo` steps in android studio?

It is limited and I want to increase number of `Ctrl Z` time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and Go to **Enter action** menu.
- Type **registry**, you can see the suggestion **Registry** on list and click on that.

[image]

- Now just type word **undo**. It automatically find for you the 'undo' options.

[image]

- By default **documentUndoLimit = 100** and **globalUndoLimit = 10**, you can change the values as you desired.